# Laravel groupBy not working with query builder

Tags: php, laravel

groupBy not working with laravel query builder

**My code here**

```
$driverData = \App\DriverProfile::select('*')
                ->leftjoin('qdm_drvr_contact', 'qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Driver_id')
                ->leftjoin('qdm_contact_type', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Contact_type_id', '=', 'qdm_contact_type.id')
                ->where('qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', "$sess_id" )
                 ->groupBy('qdm_driver.Driver_id')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: what error are you facing.

Comment: i add 3 tables with group wise one table i have 4 contacts i am using GroupBY only one contact is came so how to coming 4 contacts in one array

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$driverData =   DB::table('qdm_driver')
                ->leftjoin('qdm_drvr_contact', 'qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Driver_id')
                ->leftjoin('qdm_contact_type', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Contact_type_id', '=', 'qdm_contact_type.id')
                ->where('qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', "$sess_id" )
                 ->groupBy('qdm_driver.Driver_id')
                // ->orderby('qdm_driver.Driver_id')

                 ->get();
```

**Updated Answer**

```
$driverData =   DB::table('qdm_driver')
                ->leftjoin('qdm_drvr_contact', 'qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Driver_id')
                ->leftjoin('qdm_contact_type', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Contact_type_id', '=', 'qdm_contact_type.id')
                ->where('qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', $sess_id )
                 ->groupBy('Driver_id')
                // ->orderby('qdm_driver.qdm_driver.Driver_id')

                 ->get();
```

Comment: @chinnapureddyramakrishna: DriverProfile model create for `qdm_driver` table?

Comment: Not Working Through this error  " Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'Driver_id' in group statement is ambiguous"

Answer (score 0):

First i would use this:

```
 $driverData = DB::table('your_table')
            ->select(DB::raw('*'))
            ->leftjoin('qdm_drvr_contact', 'qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Driver_id')
            ->leftjoin('qdm_contact_type', 'qdm_drvr_contact.Contact_type_id', '=', 'qdm_contact_type.id')
            ->where('qdm_driver.Driver_id', '=', "$sess_id" )
            ->groupBy('qdm_driver.Driver_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Not Working Through this error " Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'Driver_id' in group statement is ambiguous"  This is mistake

Comment: Can you show the structure of qdm_drvr_contact and qdm_driver tables?